# Best way to bundle packages in Arch to suit my own setup

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, aur

I have started to use Arch Linux and really like it. I've got a set of packages that I install immediately on a fresh Arch install besides the base package, like JWM, iwd, sudo, git, featherpad, etc.

I was wondering if there is some way to roll all of these into one single package group, much like the 'base' package group for an easier install in future.

For example, on a fresh install, instead of entering:

```
pacstrap -S linux linux-headers linux-firmware base sudo featherpad git JWM xorg-server etc etc etc etc
```

for dozens of packages, I could just enter:

```
pacstrap -S my_base_group
```

and all of that would be included and I could easily get a consistent setup, is that possible?

Comment: I don’t think you can do this in the way you suggest. Your package group doesn’t exist in the Arch servers. However I’m sure you could write a script that would compose a pacstrap command with all the packages you want based on the contents of a text file